# Redis reaching max clients immediately on startup

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

We're having an issue hitting the max number of clients immediately after starting redis. When issuing a MONITOR command, we see thousands of INFO commands issued from our master server.

It seems to be baselining around 9000 connections most of the time. This will occasionally drop to a more normal value for our server for a couple of seconds, then it will immediately spike back to the ~9000 connections.

Anytime redis gets busy during the normal business day, we are hitting our max connections and our services start failing.

When I run the MONITOR command, this is a sample of what I see.

```
1551452385.425215 [0 192.168.100.161:54068] "info"
1551452385.425556 [0 192.168.100.161:54066] "info"
1551452385.425891 [0 192.168.100.161:54071] "info"
1551452385.426242 [0 192.168.100.161:54069] "info"
1551452385.426587 [0 192.168.100.161:54070] "info"
1551452385.426933 [0 192.168.100.161:54072] "info"
1551452385.427281 [0 192.168.100.161:54074] "info"
1551452385.427625 [0 192.168.100.161:54075] "info"
1551452385.427972 [0 192.168.100.161:54076] "info"
1551452385.428316 [0 192.168.100.161:54077] "info"
1551452385.428670 [0 192.168.100.161:54078] "info"
1551452385.429011 [0 192.168.100.161:54079] "info"
1551452385.429359 [0 192.168.100.161:54080] "info"
1551452385.429706 [0 192.168.100.161:54081] "info"
1551452385.430051 [0 192.168.100.161:54082] "info"
1551452385.430398 [0 192.168.100.161:54083] "info"
1551452385.430741 [0 192.168.100.161:54084] "info"
1551452385.431086 [0 192.168.100.161:54085] "info"
1551452385.431454 [0 192.168.100.161:54086] "info"
1551452385.431792 [0 192.168.100.161:54087] "info"
```

Our redis.conf is below.

```
daemonize yes
pidfile "/var/run/redis/redis.pid"
port 6379
tcp-backlog 2048
unixsocket "/tmp/redis.sock"
unixsocketperm 777
timeout 90
tcp-keepalive 30
loglevel notice
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis.log"
databases 16
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename "dump.rdb"
dir "/var/lib/redis"
slave-serve-stale-data yes
repl-ping-slave-period 5
maxclients 10208
slave-read-only yes
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
maxmemory-policy noeviction
appendonly yes
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
lua-time-limit 15000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 1024
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
slave-priority 1
slaveof 192.168.100.161 6379
```

Our INFO output is below.

```
# Server
redis_version:3.0.5
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:cfc7e460e931db7b
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.4.7
process_id:14289
run_id:e809f42198d0a568cc3394cee322a20c069ed682
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:35562
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:7947917
config_file:/etc/redis.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:9399
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:5357045872
used_memory_human:4.99G
used_memory_rss:5606625280
used_memory_peak:5664138480
used_memory_peak_human:5.28G
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.05
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:42
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1551451644
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:23
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:22
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_current_size:4453038609
aof_base_size:4448482140
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_rewrite_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:1

# Stats
total_connections_received:3677782
total_commands_processed:4176358
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:12
total_net_input_bytes:6261124496
total_net_output_bytes:11824027791
instantaneous_input_kbps:1.50
instantaneous_output_kbps:6.87
rejected_connections:3662459
sync_full:2
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:13406
keyspace_misses:10
pubsub_channels:1
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:104081
migrate_cached_sockets:0

# Replication
role:slave
master_host:192.168.100.161
master_port:6379
master_link_status:up
master_last_io_seconds_ago:0
master_sync_in_progress:0
slave_repl_offset:26797222
slave_priority:1
slave_read_only:1
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:7529949
repl_backlog_histlen:10344

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:326.54
used_cpu_user:1835.05
used_cpu_sys_children:303.96
used_cpu_user_children:2131.36

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=4182233,expires=1822,avg_ttl=1565571347
db4:keys=1,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
db9:keys=9957,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
db15:keys=386985,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Comment: Which redis client library are you using ? How are you creating connections to Redis ? One guess: can you verify if you are creating a new connection per command instead of reusing the same connection ?

Comment: All of the connections are new. They're coming from the redis master on a separate server. The strange thing is that the redis master only has ~400 clients at a given time. We're using the node.js client library, the php client library, and the perl client library for connecting to redis.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you seem to be creating a new redis connection every time you send a command to Redis. If  that's the case you need to reuse the same Redis connection (or create a object pool of a fixed #of connections) instead of creating a new one every time. Also, by ~400 clients if you are referring to #processes which are connected to Redis - keep in mind that 1 process can create any number of connections to Redis. Those are the connections shown in the field 'connected_clients'. Hence, #processes can be less than #connected_clients